# Process only new files in Filbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Could anyone let me know how to process only the newer files in a directory in filebeat. i have tried the below parameters in filebeat.yml , when executed its processing all the files in the path.

```
filebeat.inputs:
# filestream is an input for collecting log messages from files.
- type: filestream

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: false

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    - G:\ELK Tutorial\Logstash\My_codes\*.log
  scan_frequency: 60s
  ignore_older: 30m
  ignore_inactive: 24h
  close.on_state_change.inactive: 12h
  #compression_level: 0
  close_renamed: true
  close_removed: true
```

Comment: are you using logstash as well ? or directly from filebeat to elasticsearch ?

Comment: I am using filebeat with logstash

Comment: Hi @sudhagarramesh log input is deprecated, use Filestream input instead.

Comment: Hello @Ibra013 , i am using filestreat as an input. added the input code block.

Comment: The value of `ignore_older` needs to be greater than the value of `close.on_state_change.inactive`, this is an important note from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html#filebeat-input-filestream-ignore-older).